# CentOS chmod overiding set-group-ID?

Tags: linux, centos, chmod

I'm used to setting up SGID on a directory

`chmod -R g+s example` and then
`chmdo -R 750 example`

And have the directory and all sub-directories preserve the set-group-ID. On CentOS SGID gets overridden by the second command.

The OS is CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

In theory, and like it [says on this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html), "if commands like chmod routinely cleared these bits on directories, the mechanisms would be less convenient..." and it's exactly whats happening. `chmod -R 750` is effectivelly removing the SGID.

**How can I make `g+s` permanent?**

Comment: setgid and sticky are two different things.

Comment: @Ignacio, gonna look it deeper. Right now just corrected it so other's don't get confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `2750` with chmod instead.

Comment: thks for your reply. Using `2750` would work but it doesn't make it *permanent*. As soon as I do something like `chmod -R 640` it overrides the sticky bit. On Fedora I never had this problem...

Comment: Fedora has a newer version of coreutils.

Comment: that's it. CentOS is using quite an old version of coreutils. Thanks for catching this one!